# How to replace Adobe Air notifications icons

Tags: icons, notification, adobe-air

I have been using various tool that depend on the adobe air platform on ubuntu, like tweetdeck and grooveshark.

I have always hated, how the notification icons look, but I need them there for ease of use. Has anyone managed to change how the icons bleed into the taskbar, or even tell me where I could replace the notification icons with ones that look better. As you can see below the notication icons for skype and xchat look fine.

Please and thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two different ways to fix this problem:

1. **Change the program icons:**

   TweetDeck uses the icon `/opt/TweetDeck/share/icons/TweetDeck_128.png` for the notification area, even though there are smaller TweetDeck icons in `/opt/TweetDeck/share/icons/`.

   So as [In Protest](https://askubuntu.com/users/132/) says, just change the background of the
   icon *(`/opt/TweetDeck/share/icons/TweetDeck_128.png`)* so it matches your panel background.

   I made a TweetDeck icon for the Ambiance theme:

   - [TweetDeck_128.png](http://ubuntuone.com/p/TyK/)

   To use it, run the following commands in a terminal (assuming you downloaded it to your Desktop):

   - Back up the existing icon:

     ```
     sudo cp /opt/TweetDeck/share/icons/TweetDeck_128.png /opt/TweetDeck/share/icons/TweetDeck_128.png.bak
     ```
   - Now replace it with the new icon:

     ```
     sudo cp ~/Desktop/TweetDeck_128.png /opt/TweetDeck/share/icons/
     ```

   Result:

   - [image]
2. **Use alternate version of gnome-panel:**

   The reason the background of the icons are not transparent is because of bug [#403135 [image]](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-panel/+bug/403135).

   [Konstantinos Natsakis [image]](https://launchpad.net/~cyfex) has provided this [solution [image]](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-panel/+bug/403135/comments/187) :

   > I believe this bug is somehow related to a change in gnome-panel_1:2.29.5.1-0ubuntu1 when the building of applets as shared libraries was deactivated (they are now build as standalone executables)
   >
   > Changelog: http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/changelogs/pool/main/g/gnome-panel/gnome-panel_2.30.0-0ubuntu1/changelog
   >
   > - debian/rules:
   > - don't build in process applets during the unstable cycle so crash issues
   >     should be easier to debug and reported on the corresponding binary
   >
   > It seems to me that due to this change, the notification area icons get the background of the program's main window instead of the panel's background.
   >
   > Compiling gnome-panel with '--with-in-process-applets=notification-area' in debian/rules (and no other changes), fixes this bug for me.
   >
   > I have uploaded modified gnome-panel packages to my PPA: https://launchpad.net/~cyfex/+archive/ppa in case others want to try this (you need gnome-panel and gnome-panel-data; `killall bonobo-activation-server` and `gnome-panel` after installation)

Comment: @DoR, could you link me the icon you used for that?

Comment: @garbagecollector Done :)

Comment: @DoR i dont suppose you could provide something like that for grooveshark as well?

Comment: @garbagecollector Grooveshark icons aren't accessible, so I can't change them. See http://forums.grooveshark.com/discussion/1164/Transparent-Background-for-Grooveshark-Logo-on-Desktop-App

I have updated my answer with an alternative fix that will work for grooveshark.

Comment: @DoR is that compatible with 10.10?

Comment: @dustyprogrammer Yes.

Comment: @DoR you are the man!

Answer (score 1):

This might be a problem with Adobe Air rather than anything on the gnome side, by default icons that are passed to the gnome status icons list are transparent to the themes colour for the bar so they appear as the skype and xchat icons would.

On the other hand if the icons are passed as a non transparent image, then there is nothing that can be done except go in and fix Adobe Air's code or manually replace the icon images with a non-transparent icon which matches the colour of your theme.

Comment: @Protest okay how would you go about replacing the icon they use. I am willing to go in and edit it.

Comment: You need to unpack the programs, find the image files, identify the image file used in the icon, manually edit it.